# Using VBA for keyword search, then relative copy-paste into separate workbook

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am currently trying to figure out a way to use VBA to look through all sheets in an active workbook for a keyword, for example "wheel", then copy a cell range relative to the position of the keyword, and finally paste it into a specific cell on a separate workbook. I have figured out how to activate and loop through all sheets on an active workbook but am struggling with my keyword search across all sheets and the relative copy and paste functionality. For clarification upon this, if "wheel" was in cell A1, I would like to copy a given cell range (let's say 3 columns over, 16 columns down), two rows down from that. So if "wheel" is in cell A1, I would want to copy cell range A3:D19, if "wheel" is in cell A25, I would want to copy cell range A27:D43. Let me know if further clarification is needed, I am happy to provide.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim c As Integer
Dim n As Integer
c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For n = 1 To c Step 1
    Last = Worksheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For I = Last To 1 Step -1
            Set james = Selection.Find(What:="Wheel", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
                        :=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
                        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            If james = "wheel" Then
        
        Next I
    Next n  
End Sub
```

Here is my current code, I have tried various combinations of copy paste and havent been able to get it to work properly. I figured if I assign my find function to a variable I could use an if-else statement to validate whether or not the keyword is present, if it is I would copy cell range and paste in the respective workbook, if not I would paste a given string such as "Error! check previous report" in the aforementioned workbook.

Comment: `Set james = Selection..` - Don't use `Select`. You don't ever change what's selected, and also you're using `ActiveCell` and `Activate`, and missing something if `James = "wheel"`...is this complete? You have a few big errors in here.

Comment: @BruceWayne, apologies for the errors as I don't understand the syntax or conventions of the language and am being forced to learn as I go. "If James = 'wheel'" is a start of my thought process for a validation statement in pursuit of my copy function, and I was going to include an else statement to print an error in a given cell if either the array or keyword wasn't found.

Comment: Are you expecting only a single match per sheet, or could there be >1 match?

Comment: @TimWilliams there is a possibility there's more than one match, I am focusing on getting the initial process stamped out before I work on creating a case that would include contingencies for a second or third match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim n As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim matches As Collection, c As Range
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For n = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count Step 1
        With wb.Worksheets(n)
            Set matches = FindAll( _
                .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row), _
                "Wheel", xlPart)
        End With
        'loop over any matching cells
        For Each c In matches
            'do something with c
            c.Offset(2).Resize(17, 4).Copy
            '...then paste somewhere?
        Next c
    Next n
End Sub

'return a collection of all cells in range `rng` matching `val`
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String, matchType As XlLookAt) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=matchType, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()
    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```